# Can external SharePoint Online user be added to add-in (app) license?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, licensing

There is a SharePoint hosted add-in (app) installed from Office Store, which uses standard Office Store licensing (and API for license validation).

SharePoint Online portal has some external users ([like described here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85)).

External users have "edit" rights on site where add-in (app) is deployed. They can see the add-in (app) in Site Contents and even open some configuration pages for the add-in (app) where license is not validated.

When external user tries to open the add-in (app) he receives message that he does not have valid license for the add-in (app).

When I go to `Office 365\Administrator\ADMIN\SharePoint\Apps\Manage licenses` and try to include the external user to add-in (app) license the user can not be picked.

Is is possible to add external user to add-in (app) license?